# How do I use sqlmetal to generate an internal (not public) data context

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, dbml, sqlmetal

I'd like to use sqlmetal to generate dbml data contexts for my project, but the data context and all classes created are marked as `public`. As this is supposed to be an API layer I'd like to instead mark many of these classes or at least the context itself as `internal`. Is there a way to do this in sqlmetal or some other tool without having to go in and edit the dbml by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is one of the options that you can't do directly at the command line. You may indeed have to edit the dbml. However, this isn't a tricky change, so you should be able to automate it with a basic command-line tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using my [LINQ to SQL template](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/09/14/linq-to-sql-template-for-visual-studio-2008) that provides a drop-in replacement for the DBML to C#/VB.NET code generation process that you can completely customize.

[)amien